# symbolic mathematics in algorithms

Tags: algorithm, math

I am going throgh algorithms. It is mentioned that one of the application of algorithms is symbolic mathematics. And I found following defintion from dictionary as below.

> The use of computers to manipulate mathematical equations and
>   expressions in symbolic form, as opposed to manipulating the numerical
>   quantities represented by those symbols. Such a system might be used
>   for symbolic integration or differentiation, substitution of one
>   expression into another, simplification of an expression, change of
>   subject etc.  One of the best known symbolic mathematics software
>   packages is Mathematica.

My question what does statement "equations and expressions in symbolic form, as opposed to manipulating the numerical quantities represented by those symbols."  mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question what does statement "equations and expressions in symbolic
>   form, as opposed to manipulating the numerical quantities represented
>   by those symbols." mean?

By the second, something like this is meant:

```
>>> x = 2.3
>>> y = 9.8
>>> z = x+2*y
>>> z
21.900000000000002
>>> type(z)
<type 'float'>
```

where you're treating `x`, `y`, and `z` as names for numbers.  You're using the computer as an old-fashioned calculator, where it only does arithmetic.  `z = x+2*y` performs the arithmetic operations described on the right and associates the resulting number to `z`.

By the "symbolic form", something more like this is meant:

```
sage: x, y, z = var("x y z")
sage: z == x+2*y
z == x + 2*y
sage: eq = z == x+2*y
sage: eq
z == x + 2*y
sage: type(z)
<type 'sage.symbolic.expression.Expression'>
sage: parent(eq)
Symbolic Ring
sage: eq.solve(y)
[y == -1/2*x + 1/2*z]
```

where `x`,`y`, and `z` can be expressions, or variables in some structure, rather than merely names for specific numbers, and higher-level operations can be performed.